# Where do the tags in Sarn Slums come from?

Tags: path-of-exile

I found a weid tag on some of the [Sarn Slums](http://en.pathofexilewiki.com/wiki/Sarn_Slums) walls.  It pictures the letter "V" in a golden crown on a red background.  Any idea where it comes from ?  Is it a simple cosmetic element, or it is part of the scenario ?

[image: Tag in Sarn Slums]

[image: Tag in Sarn Slums]

Comment: From what I can find, these symbols are just another paragraph in the volume of untold stories in Wraeclast, that your character isn't directed to uncover/doesn't care about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe they are related to the Purity Rebellion, in which Emperor Chitus was overthrown by High Templar Voll, the People's Poet Victario, mayor Ondar of Sarn, and some of their friends. The overturned crown represents rebellion, and the V would be for Voll, who lead the rebellion, or Victario, who seems like he'd be more popular with the people who lived in the slums.